# Evaluation of InverseFunction at the boundaries of its domain

Tags: evaluation, inverse

Folks,

I want to numerically evaluate a `InverseFunction` `h[x]` close to the edges `x5` and `x2` of its domain, with no success up to now. As you can see below, `h[x]` can only be evaluated sufficiently far from these points, which will not be suitable in my case.

I suspect I can use some hidden option of `InverseFunction` like `MaxIterations`. How can I properly perform this evaluation (in particular the `NIntegrate`)?

The code is

```
Block[{f, if, g, ig, h, ih, x0, y0, x2, x3, y3, x4, x5, y5, ph2, ph3, 

  cont, norm}, With[{d = 10^-4, r = 10^-8, s = .005, L = 16, n = 10^6},

  if[x_] := -((L s)/(d Log[s/(# r)]))
    ProductLog[-((
    d # Log[s/(# r)] n^(1/L) (s/(# r))^-((d #)/(L s)) )/(L s))] &[x];

  f[x_] := InverseFunction[-((L s)/(d Log[s/(# r)]))
     ProductLog[-((
     d # Log[s/(# r)] n^(1/L) (s/(# r))^-((d #)/(L s)) )/(
     L s))] &][x];

  h[x_] := InverseFunction[-((L s)/(d Log[s/(# r)]))
     ProductLog[-1, -((
     d # Log[s/(# r)] n^(1/L) (s/(# r))^-((d #)/(L s)) )/(
     L s))] &][x];

  ih[x_] := -((L s)/(d Log[s/(# r)]))
    ProductLog[-1, -((
    d # Log[s/(# r)] n^(1/L) (s/(# r))^-((d #)/(L s)) )/(L s))] &[x];

  ig[x_] := InverseFunction[(s Log[1/n] + d # Log[s/(# r)])/(
  d Log[s/(# r)]) &][x];

  g[x_] := (s Log[1/n] + d # Log[s/(# r)])/(d Log[s/(# r)]) &[x];

  y3 = Re[y3] /. FindRoot[if[y3] == ih[y3], {y3, 25}];
  x3 = if[y3];

  x4 = ig[.001];
  x2 = ih[.001];

  y5 = Re[y5] /. FindRoot[ih[y5] == ig[y5], {y5, 10}, MaxIterations -> 1000];
  x5 = ih[y5];

  (* Here my problem is evident *)
  Print[{y5, h[x5], h[1.02 x5], h[1.019 x5]}];
  Print[{x2, h[x2], h[.94 x2], h[.98 x2]}]

  (* Here is the operation I want to perform *)
NIntegrate[1, {a, .001, f[y5]}, {c, x5, ih[a]}, {b, Max[a, if[a]], 
Min[c, h[c]]}]

]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: you should try to provide a more minimal example. The issue here is only that `h[x]` does not evaluate for `77~<x~<97`. Everything else is just distracting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the function you want to invert becomes complex out of range. Here are a couple of approaches:

```
With[{d = 10^-4, r = 10^-8, s = .005, L = 16, n = 10^6},
 f[y_] := -((L s)/(d Log[s/(y r)])) 
        ProductLog[-1, -((d y
            Log[s/(y r)] n^(1/L) (s/(y r))^-((d y)/(L s)))/(L s))];
 myh[x_] := y /. FindMinimum[Abs[f[y] - x], {y, 10}][[2, 1]];
 myh2[x_] := 
  y /. FindMinimum[Re[#] + 1000 Im[#] &@ (f[y]  - x)^2, {y, 10}][[2,1]]]

 myh[80]
```

> 14.2824

```
 myh2[80]
```

> 14.2824

Of course for robustness you should add a check that the min is actually
near zero.

I think you'll find these same tricks will speed up finding your other roots as well.

Comment: Thanks, george2079. The function itself works great. The problem is that it does not work inside `NIntegrate`. The integration I want to perform is `NIntegrate[1, {a, .001, f[y5]}, {c, x5, ih[if[a]]}, {b, if[a], 
  myh[c]}]`. If I use `c` or `Exp[c]` instead of `myh[c]` an integration is performed, but not with your function yet. I've been trying to use `Hold` in its definition with `ReleaseHold` at `NIntegrate`, with no avail.

Comment: `ReleaseHold[
 NIntegrate[
  1, {a, .001, myf[y5]}, {c, x5, ih[if[a]]}, {b, if[a], 
   Hold[myh[c]]}]]` finally worked out, with lots of messages though. Perhaps to ask how to do the same but circumventing them may be worthwhile. Thanks again, george2079.